# Помогите найти ошибку и немного усовершенствовать код

Tags: c++

Ошибка заключается в том что перед of и after после запуска кода появляються знаки вопроса.
А усовершенствовать так чтобы для величин a, b, c, d можно было ввести своё значение не в самом коде програми, а уже непосредственно после её запуска.

```
#include <iostream>

void my_swap(int& n, int& m)
{
    int temp = n;
    n = m;
    m = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
    std::cout << "Initial values ​​of variables: " << "a = " << a << " ,b = " << b << " ,c = " << c << " ,d = " << d << std::endl;
    my_swap(a, b);
    my_swap(c, d);
    std::cout << "Variable values ​​after exchange: " << "a = " << a << " ,b = " << b << " ,c = " << c << " ,d = " << d;
}
```

Comment: "U+200B ​ e2 80 8b ZERO WIDTH SPACE"

Comment: `для величин a, b, c, d можно было ввести своё значение не в самом коде программы, а уже непосредственно после её запуска.` - что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Сейчас код написан так, что он будет виводить только уже вписанные значения в самом коде, а мне нужно чтобы после запуска програми, пользователь сам вводил цифри. Например: Введите а=...

Answer (score 2):

Удалите лишние 2 символа перед of и value, они там есть, просто на экране невидимы...

Вот кусочек дампа ваших исходников:

```
00000000A0: 20 20 20 73 74 64 3A 3A │ 63 6F 75 74 20 3C 3C 20     std::cout <<
00000000B0: 22 49 6E 69 74 69 61 6C │ 20 76 61 6C 75 65 73 20  "Initial values
00000000C0: E2 80 8B E2 80 8B 6F 66 │ 20 76 61 72 69 61 62 6C  вЂ‹вЂ‹of variabl
00000000D0: 65 73 3A 20 22 20 3C 3C │ 20 22 61 20 3D 20 22 20  es: " << "a = "
```

Comment: Как я понял всё дело в (вЂ‹вЂ‹), если да, то как мне их убрать?

Comment: Ну, знаете... В редакторе работать умеете? Там, с помощью клавиши Delete или Backspace, или выделив... Это уже вопрос за гранью :)